# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

this is what i use

```
 {{ $joburi->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() }}
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Models\Joburi;
use App\Models\SkillsEmployee;
use App\Models\ProfileEmployee;
use App\Models\ProfileEmployer;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JoburiController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        {
            $joburi = Joburi::where('activ', 1)->limit(15)->get();
            $skill = SkillsEmployee::all();
            $employerimage = ProfileEmployer::where('uid', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $profileimage = ProfileEmployee::where('uid', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            return view('joburiactive', compact('joburi', 'skill', 'employerimage', 'profileimage'));
        }
    }
```

in other controller works with no problem

does anyone know why do i get this error?

Comment: Can you show where you define `$joburi` in the other controller? `appends` is part of the pagination class, while you're just getting a regular collection of 15 objects here.

Comment: i found the problem, i have to use ```$joburi = Joburi::where('activ', 1)->sortable()->paginate(5);```

Comment: because get method used in your ```$joburi``` variable assignment returns a ```Collection```

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method you call on your $joburi query returns a Collection and not a single record. Maybe you should try `first()` or some other methods which aren‘t returning a Collection. Or you should find a different way to process the Collection so it fits your requirements.